# Applied dielectric grease to an exposed wire to the starter

Tags: electrical, vw

Greetings and salutations.

Yesterday as I was working on my car i notice some exposed copper wire leading to my starter. 5 minutes later after a slight grinding sound while driving downhill the car stopped , no power.
I turned the key  but absolutely nothing occured , no attempt to start or turn  ,, nothing. Now with the key out of the ignition the dashboard symbols all light up and stay on. So , I have disconnected the negative cable from the battery for now.  So does anyone know if i have done something to the ecu or could it simply be a fuse thats blown or a relay or would it be possible that the starter or starter solenoid are beyond repair
  Where do i start before i start to make things worse.
**2002 VW cabrio  automatic**

Comment: Welcome to the stack! One thing I'd recommend is editing your post to be a little more linear and make the question good and clear. That said, it is *possible* that you've damaged the ECU, however that is not likely the cause of the lighting being on while the key is out. Most likely you've dead shorted something I think. It is definitely *not* because of a fuse, but a relay *could* also be the culprit. I have seen them get fused from crazy draw before.

Comment: Starter. But first, what were you working on the other day?  Also, why was the copper wire exposed? - Did the insulation melt off? And which lead was exposed? Got any pics of the starter, fuse box, dash lights, or whatever you were working on?